# Can I make Account Owner read only?

Tags: administration, validation, profile

This is my issue

Users assigned to a particular profile who cannot change the account owner.

I went into the profile to set OwnerId to readonly and cant do it at profile level for some reason.

The other way i used was to go to the object account > Account Owner > set field level security which i cant

So i opted to write validation rule

```
AND ( ISCHANGED( OwnerId), 

RecordType.Id = "000D0000000xxxx",

RecordType.Id = "000D0000000xxxx", 

$Profile.Id <>'000D0000000xxxx')
```

This is not working as well. can anyone suggest me how can i assign readonly permission on a single profile

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the Account Owner field as Read only in the page layout assigned to those profiles.

[image]

But **the recommended approach** is to use a validation rule, like this:

```
AND ( 
  ISCHANGED( OwnerId), 
  OR(
    RecordType.Id = "000D0000000xxxx",
    RecordType.Id = "000D0000000xxxx" 
  ),
  $Profile.Id <>'000D0000000xxxx'
)
```

Because then even if the user triggers the change through the API, for example, the platform will validate this change. Doing the "lock" just on the page layout does not prevent this.